# When constructing an orientation matrix, are the rows of the matrix the axis?

Tags: mathematics, graphics-programming, matrix

When constructing an orientation matrix, are the rows of the matrix the axis?

The matrix is row-major and I'm multiplying vectors on the right (Mv).  So, the matrix looks like

```
r0c0 r0c1 r0c2
r1c0 r1c1 r1c2
r2c0 r2c1 r2c2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a mathematical point of view, it depends on in which order you are multiplying the vectors with the matrix.

- Using a row-vector (`v`) and multiplying it with a matrix (`A`) as `v∙A`, then the rows will act as the axes.
- Using a column-vector (`v`) and multiplying a matrix (`A`) with it as `A∙v`, then the columns will act as the axes.

Answer (score 2):

That depends, if it is in row major form then yes, for column major form no.

Where does this matrix come from?

Comment: Please elaborate.  Did I give you enough info to do so?